# Hibernate java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, hibernate, web-applications, tomcat7

I have a Java web application running on Tomcat 7 - jdk1.7

This application uses Spring 4.1.5.RELEASE and Hibernate 4.2.2.Final

My problem is a OutOfMemoryException of the Heap space on building section factory

This is my static method that opens a SessionFactory

```
public class GenericDAO {

    public static SessionFactory sessionFactory = null;
    public static ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = null;

    Transaction tx = null;

    public static SessionFactory createSessionFactory() {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.configure();
        serviceRegistry = new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(
            configuration.getProperties()). buildServiceRegistry();
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

And this is an example of DAO

```
public class SpecificDAO extends GenericDAO {
    public int save(MyObject item) {
        Session session = createSessionFactory().openSession();
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(item);
            tx.commit();
            return item.getId();
        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null) tx.rollback();
                 e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

The error occurs at the line containing

**sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);**

The problem doesn't occur immediately at the deploy, but after 2 o 3 days of usage

This is my Hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.XX.XXX:1433;databaseName=DatabaseName</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">username</property>
    <property name="connection.password">password</property>
    <mapping class="it.company.client.project.hibernate.MyObject"/>

    <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
    <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Can you show your hibernate.cfg.xml?

Comment: Why do you create the SessionFactory on each save() call? You can instantiate it just once and reuse.

Comment: I bet your program works not very fast.

Comment: added hbm config. @StainslavL how to instantiate only 1 time? whith a static variable? Singleton?

Comment: @user1516873 I cannot evaluate because this app execute Full Text Serch and, yes, is not so fast, but I don't know the causes

Answer (score 2):

You have to create the session factory only once as it is a heavy weight object, refer to the [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch01.html#tutorial-firstapp-helpers) for its details.

Here is the sample code from the doc on how it should be created:

```
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            return new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory(
                new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().build() );
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is better idea to flush and clear the session after used, you can use both

```
session.flush();
session.clear();
```

for more information [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869473/hibernate-out-of-memory-exception-while-processing-large-collection-of-elements) and [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136785/hibernate-causes-out-of-memory-exception-when-saving-large-number-of-entities)

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a SessionFactory object for every save() call.

i.e you are creating a new SessionFactory repeatedly for every save() call but not closing the existing SessionFactory objects in memory.

How many times save() is called ? the same no of SessionFactory  will be in memory, which causes the memory leak.

SessionFactory are heavy weight objects, so you'd create at application initialization. You can create a SingleTon to instantiate SessionFactory.

Comment: But this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14411979/4759176 says that SesssionFactory is *already* a singleton. Then it's not true, then?

Answer (score 1):

Avoid instantiation of SessionFactory object on every DAO action. It is **very slow** and causes memory leaks. Better explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14411979/1516873)

If you're using `Spring` anyway, better to delegate to `Spring` work with  SessionFactory, transactions and handling SQL exceptions. For example, your save() method will reduce to one line of code `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(item);` Manual transaction open/commit/rollback should be replaced with `@Transactional` attribute. Also, usually better place transactions on whole service method, not on every single DAO method, but it depends of business logic.

[Here](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-4-and-hibernate-4-integration-tutorial-part-1-xml-configuration) example how to configure spring context for work with `Hibernate` (just first article for google)

I slightly adopted this example for current question

```
@Repository
public class SpecificDAO {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Autowired
    public SpecificDAO(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public int save(MyObject item) {
        try{
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(item);
        }catch (HibernateException e) {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Spring configuration

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="it.company.client.project"/>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.XX.XXX:1433;databaseName=DatabaseName"/>
    <property name="username" value="username"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>it.company.client.project.hibernate.MyObject</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <!--prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop-->
            </props>
        </property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```